# Is it possible to have 2 sequential onclick actions for one <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem where if a user clicks on an anchor tag something happens,
eg. `<a onClick={this.Submission}><Icon/></a>` , but now I also want a confirmation box on click of this anchor link, and only if its value is true.
So, in short I need two sequential actions to happen on click of one link, first a confirmation box and if its true then the other action.

Comment: No, it is not. Just have the one click call a function that does two different things.

Comment: Its kinda the same action really, confirmation + the actual action.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Could you consider adding your comment as an answer? With a small code example, preferably.

Comment: @kingdaro - Considering I know absolutely nothing about ReactJS (and the associated policies regarding inline event handlers), it's probably best left to someone with experience specific to ReactJS. But HTML / JavaScript certainly says that you can't have two click events :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summarising your question**
You want to be able to perform two simultanious actions based on a single click

**Solution**
Using an onclick attribute within the anchor element, call a JavaScript function
Inside the javascript script, passing this object to the function

Then the function receives the object which we can call el for element and then forward the object onto two other functions as such

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="funAnchorClick(this)">Click me</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function funAchorClick(el){
    funProcessOne(el);
    funProcessTwo(el);
}
function funProcessOne(el){
    el.style.background="#F00";
}
function funProcessTwo(el){
    el.style.color="FFF";
}
```

The first function passed the object on to the other 2 functions allowing you to control the same DOM Element from seperate functions

Hope that answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have more than one action occur when you click an  tag. You'll just need to call a function that performs two tasks.

Like this:

```
<a onclick="anchorFunction()">Anchor Tag</a>

<script>
  function anchorFunction() {
    console.log("Action a");
    console.log("Action b");
  }
</script>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle for it if you want to tinker with it.](https://jsfiddle.net/4hstqe77/)